# place my custom interceptor after default org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor in cxf

Tags: java, spring-security, cxf, wss4j

I want to create a custom interceptor to access the x.509 certificate, and as I have read here:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?100159-ProviderNotFoundException-wiring-CXF-s-WSS4JInInterceptor-with-Spring-Security.

I have to create an interceptor after the default org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor
But I can't find any clue about wehre should I configure this. By the way I'm using spring xml configuration.

```
 <jaxws:inInterceptors >
            <!--<bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor" >-->
                <!--<constructor-arg>-->
                    <!--<map>-->
                        <!--<entry key="action" value="Signature"/>-->
                        <!--<entry key="signaturePropFile" value="server-crypto.properties"/>-->
                        <!--<entry key="signatureKeyIdentifier" value="serverkey"/>-->
                        <!--<entry key="passwordCallbackClass" value="com.kprtech.service.ws.impl.ServerCallback"/>-->
                    <!--</map>-->
                <!--</constructor-arg>-->
            <!--</bean>-->
            <bean class="com.kprtech.service.ws.service2.MyWSS4JInInterceptor"  >

            </bean>
        </jaxws:inInterceptors>
```

I have read that adding an interceptor after the WSS4J default interceptor would allow me to access the certificate in another interceptor executed after, but I can't find any way to change the order in which certificates executes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the addAfter() method of the AbstractPhaseInterceptor in your interceptor's constructor.

See [detailes here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html).

Can you post your interceptor's code?